# Join or Union in 5 tables on DATE clause

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, union

My client have a database and inside have 5 tables, right now without relationship, just the date in each table. I know that these will be maybe impossible but my client need a report with the info in this tables. He need join the row `profession` that right now are in 4 of 5 tables with the `amount` and `userId` in the last one, all these with `between` dates. So I tried `INNER JOIN` ed all tables and in `ON` clause make the relation with the `date` row.

Here are the TABLES:

```
---DATES---

userId ---- Int
username -- varchar 150
amount ---- Float(5,2)
date ------ DATETIME


--- TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4 --- (same rows for different parts in the program)(have more rows than those)

profession --- varchar 100
date -------- DATETIME
userId ------ Int
```

I made this type of `INNER JOIN`, but right now, not shown any respond, without any error in console. so I don't know if there is another form to do this for show me the info that the client need:

```
<?php
$fromdate = filter_var($_POST["fromdate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$todate = filter_var($_POST["todate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 try{
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%d de %M de %Y') AS date,
C.userId, C.username, C.amount, (D.profession) AS diag1, (DN.profession) AS diag2, 
(X.professions) AS diag3, (DJ.profession) AS diag4 FROM DATES C,
INNER JOIN DIAGNOSTICO D
INNER JOIN DIAGNOSTICON DN
INNER JOIN CONSULTA X
INNER JOIN DIAGNOSTICOJUR DJ
ON DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(D.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
AND DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(DN.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
AND DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(X.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
AND DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(DJ.date, '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE C.date BETWEEN '".$fromdate."' AND '".$todate."' ORDER BY C.date ASC");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $row["userId"]; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php echo $row["diag1"].''.$row["diag2"].''.$row["diag3"].''.$row["diag4"]; ?>'
        </td> //
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried with the date row because the client save only once the `amount` in the `DATES` table. That same day he (the client), save in the profession row only once , in which table? that depends on what the client has done to the user.(The program have multiple forms)

Comment: This will only show dates that appear in **all 5 tables**. If a date is missing from any table, the rows in the other tables with that date will be ignored.

Comment: @Barmar  I saw all the dates in those tables and all of them have a date inside, any of those havent these `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: I mean they have to have matching dates. If you have data for `2018-04-20` in 3 tables, but not the last table, that date won't be shown.

Comment: If amount relates to money, then it's unlikely to want to be FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, so you will get rows for the date even if they don't have a match in one of the other tables.
You'll need to use a separate `ON` clause for each join, to specify that specific relationship. If one of the tables is missing data for a specific date, you'll get `NULL` for the columns from that table.

Since you're using PDO, you should use `bindParam()` rather than substituting variables into the query.

You also had an extra `,` after `FROM DATES C`, causing a syntax error.

And use `DATE(columnname)` rather than `DATE_FORMAT()`.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(C.date, '%d de %M de %Y') AS date,
C.userId, C.username, C.amount, (D.profession) AS diag1, (DN.profession) AS diag2, 
(X.professions) AS diag3, (DJ.profession) AS diag4 
FROM DATES C
LEFT JOIN DIAGNOSTICO D ON DATE(C.date) = DATE(D.date)
LEFT JOIN DIAGNOSTICON DN ON DATE(C.date) = DATE(DN.date)
LEFT JOIN CONSULTA X ON DATE(C.date) = DATE(X.date)
LEFT JOIN DIAGNOSTICOJUR DJ ON DATE(C.date) = DATE(DJ.date)
WHERE C.date BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ORDER BY C.date ASC");
$sql->bindParam(':fromdate', $fromdate);
$sql->bindParam(':todate', $todate);
```

Comment: Nice! That works perfect! the extra `,` I added here when I type the post. Thank you, you save my day!